# Nerdery CP Theme - Grid UI Issue with Reordering Rows?

Tags: grid, cp-themes

This is a minor issue and there are surely more important questions to be answered.

But I am using the Nerdery CP theme and noticed an issue with the UI of the Grid fieldtype.

When I try to reorder Grid rows (in EE 2.7.3 and 2.8.1), I cannot drag rows between other rows, they just jump to the bottom or top of the set. I made a quick video to demonstrate: http://youtu.be/p8-5OjqnDd0)

If I turn off the Nerdery CP theme, then the reordering seems to work fine (but that's a drag -- so to speak -- because Nerdery looks so much cleaner and less pink).

Alas, the Nerdery devot-ee forum is archived only, so I was wondering if anyone has noticed this issue and possibly resolved it in the override CSS?

Answer (score 2):

there. Thanks for pointing this out. I haven't noticed it in my environments, but I'll take another look. In the mean time if you know the fix you can send a pull request to https://github.com/litzinger/Nerdery-Theme

Comment: Thanks Brian... it appears to be: .ui-sortable-placeholder that is the cause.  What is that used for?

Comment: Has a fix ever been found for this issue?